# How to create a function to get next id of element in jquery and call this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a custom function `goToNext()` it's just supposed to alert the id of the next element that i've clicked on.

I want to call this custom function inside another click function.

For now when I click on first element it alerts `id_2` (next from the first, so it's ok) but if you click the second element it doesn't return `id_3` (like it's supposed to be) but it return `id_2` same if you click on the last element (supposed to alert the first)

this is my [jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/y0dc5ooc/3/)

```js
function goToNext() {
  var get_next_id = $('.btn').next().attr("id");
  alert(get_next_id);
}

$('.btn').click(function() {
  goToNext();
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" id="id-1">
  1
</div>
<div class="btn" id="id-2">
  2
</div>
<div class="btn" id="id-3">
  3
</div>
```

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/y0dc5ooc/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this`

```js
function goToNext(thisObj){
var get_next_id = $(thisObj).next().attr("id");
  if(get_next_id!=undefined)
      alert(get_next_id);
  else
      alert($(thisObj).parents().find("div:first").attr("id"));
}

$('.btn').click(function(){
goToNext(this);
});
```

```css
.btn{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="btn" id="id-1">
1
</div>
<div class ="btn" id="id-2">
2
</div>
<div class ="btn" id="id-3">
3
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function goToNext($btn){
var get_next_id = $btn.next().attr("id");
alert(get_next_id);
}

$('.btn').click(function(){
goToNext($(this));
});
```

Comment: @Sushi Btw, you can even shorten it a bit by using `$('.btn').click(goToNext)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reference `this`

```
function goToNext(e){
    var get_next_id = $(e).next().attr("id");
    alert(get_next_id);
}

$('.btn').click(function(){
    goToNext(this);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0dc5ooc/5/)